# How to find area under the curve of a signal?

Tags: arduino, adc, wheatstone-bridge

I am using a **Wheatstone Bridge** circuit with one pressure sensor. I want to find the area under the curve as the signal goes from 0 to maximum to 0 again. I have tried to use ADC of Arduino and then use the counter to count++ as long as the signal is not zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNxO57.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above values are not exact.

What I want to ask is how can I find the area under the curve of this signal. If I simply add all the signals then the variable which is storing the result might get overflowed. I want to find the area and print it on a display or something like that. Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: "the result might get overflowed" - this is where you .... use a bigger variable ...

Comment: Use a larger data type ? Decrease your sample time ?

Comment: Even long int might get overflow. I want to ask if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you are worried about overflow then do the change from "0 to maximum to 0 again" more quickly. This uses fewer samples and the total is smaller.

Comment: I don't have any control over the sensor so I can't change the time between the sensor output going from 0-max-0. Can I do integration without adding the values? (any better methods?)

Comment: *"Can I do integration without adding the values?"* - If you can, I'd be *really* interested to find out how.

Comment: @RogerRowland Find a function which describes the signal, and calculate the definite integral of that function. Implementation details are left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: @AndrewMorton *"find a function..."* .... Yeah, right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply measure the voltage via the ADC at exact periodic time intervals and keep a running sum calculation from zero-crossing to zero- crossing. The result would have the units of volt-seconds because the y-axis of the measured curve is voltage and the x-axis is time.

So that, you would need to invoke your ADC reading routine in a well-calibrated timing loop, or trigger it from a timer interrupt. You will activate this process from positive zero-cross to the next positive zero-cross; or, you can do it between negative zero-crosses.

In the case of your bridge you must make a differential measurement: Out2 - Out1 or Out1 - Out2 depending on how the pressure transducer works.If the wave is bidirectional (voltages above Out1 for half the cycle and below it for the other half), you need to treat both half-cycles as though they are positive excursions. In other words, take the absolute value of the voltage reading. This is the case because areas, by their nature, are always positive.

As a practical matter, the running sum of the ADC readings will get very large. The final sum will depend on how many readings you take per cycle. You handle this in your program by typing the running sum as a larger numeric variable type such as a long integer, double integer, long word, or even a floating point.

You will then divide the total running sum of the ADC voltage readings by the number of ADC readings/second and then by the number of ADC counts/volt to scale the answer to the units of volt-seconds. Although, if all you need is a relative area-under-the-curve to compare different operational scenarios, you can dispense with these final divisions and simply use the running sum albeit it very large number.

If you need to make just one calculation of one isolated cycle, the program is pretty simple. If you need to make sequential cycle-to-cycle readings, the program gets more complex because you will not have time to make the final calculations of area between zero-crossings. In this case you need to use a foreground process to direct the ADC readings and make the calculations and a background process to actually take the ADC measurements - or visa versa. Another approach, if your application allows it is to take ADC measurements on alternate (e.g. even) cycles, and make the calculations during the other cycle (e.g. odd).

Answer (score 0):

How precise does the measurement have to be? If it doesn't have to be super precise, try using a `float` type instead of `long int`. After each result, divide by some arbitrary constant to keep the numbers lower. Sum these smaller numbers, then multiply the final result by the same constant. You will lose some precision, but likely will get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your signal is positive.

```
uint32_t integrateL = 0; integrateH=0; temp;
double   value;

.
.
.

adc_newvalue = GetADC();

while (adc_newvalue > 0) {
    temp = integrateL;

    integrateL += adc_newvalue; 

    if (integrateL < temp)
        integrateH++;

    value = (double)(integrateH) * (1<<32) + (double)(integrateL);

    Serial.println(value);

    adc_newvalue = GetADC();
}
```

Comment: if (integrateL < temp)
            integrateH++;
    
        value = (double)(integrateH) * (1<<32) + (double)(integrateL);                                                                                              Can you please explain these lines?

Comment: Let's start with the if.. part. What do you think it does?

Comment: If the integrate signal turns out to be negative then increment integrateH++. But you assumed the signal to be positive so it is not necessary? Am I right?

Comment: Look at the types. integrateL can't be negative because it's unsigned.

Comment: So the loop won't execute? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You're worried about an overflow. What happens when that happens?

Answer (score 0):

I would try implementing an integrator in hardware with one opamp and some circuitry to reset the integrator value. From there, you can measure the sum of the signal with the ADC. I am sure this method will give you more accurate results.